# Web deploy on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Server 2012 and want to do a web deploy / publish to the IIS server installed there. It complains that it cannot reach the server and suggests to:

```
You can ping the remote machine
That the msdepsvc or wmsvc service is started on the remote server.
Your firewall is not blocking incoming connections of your ports on the destination. If you used the default installation, then it would be 80 for msdepsvc and 8172 for wmsvc.
```

I have pretty much done all of those but Web Deploy refuses to connect. I tested this with a Windows 2008 R2 server and it works fine.

Comment: Windows Firewall? Can you successfully telnet to those ports?

Comment: And did you grant the user you're trying to connect as permissions to publish in IIS?

Comment: Yes on the user question. Trying telnet now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link details every step for enabling web deploy on windows server 2012.

[Configuring web deploy](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/gabe/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/)

Comment: Welcome to serverfault!  Generally, though links can be helpful, people will appreciate it if you give an explanation or point at something specific the asker might have omitted to do.